# React / Starting server with Serve not working

Tags: linux

In my server I have a django & a react projet. Django runs correctly on port 8000. I have also tried to run a React project on port 3000 with :

```
serve -s build -l 3000
```

But here is the log with

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

[image: screenshot]

IT seems to me the IP is missing. Is there a way to configure Serve command ?

EDIT
When I run `serve -s build` I got this message :

> ERROR: Cannot copy server address to clipboard: Couldn't find the
> `xsel` binary and fallback didn't work. On Debia│    "node":
> "^16.17.0",
> n/Ubuntu you can install xsel with: sudo apt install xsel.

Comment: Is it possible that you have your React project only listening for IPv6? I would expect your net stay output to show listening on IPv4 only or both IPv4 and IPv6. Currently, it is only showing as listening on IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

I fand the solution in SO

To start the server I needed tu use -n flag

```
serve -n -s build
```

When I was running  without the flag, I got this warning :

> ERROR: Cannot copy server address to clipboard: Couldn't find the
> `xsel` binary and fallback didn't work. On Debia    "node":
> "^16.17.0", n/Ubuntu you can install xsel with: sudo apt install xsel.